# How to reference an object from inside a private function

Tags: php, pdo, mixpanel

I am using [Mixpanel](http://www.mixpanel.com)'s PHP API and want to call `mp->track`.

In this case, the `mp->track` is defined as an object in the mixpanel library, called via `require(mixpanel.php)`.

Typically, this would work fine:

```
require ('mixpanel-php/lib/Mixpanel.php');
$mp = Mixpanel::getInstance("XXX");
$mp->track('Session');
```

However, I want to call `mp->track()` from within a private function, but the following gives an `object not defined` error:

```
require ('mixpanel-php/lib/Mixpanel.php');
$mp = Mixpanel::getInstance("XXX")

private function startSession() {

$mp->track('Session');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `$mp` variable is not accessible in the scope of the `startSession()` method. This is because it is not `global`. One solution would be to set the `$mp` global, but this is not a good software design. You should either pass it as a function variable

```
private function startSession($mp) {
    $mp->track('Session');
}
```

or you should get the instance itself in the private method

```
private function startSession() {
    Mixpanel::getInstance("XXX")->track('Session');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach; if you define

```
$mp = Mixpanel::getInstance("XXX");
```

somewhere in your class; you should use it as

```
$this->mp->track('Session');
```

So your code should simply look like

```
<?php
  require ('mixpanel-php/lib/Mixpanel.php');

  class MyClass {
    protected $mp;
    public function __construct() {
      $this->mp = Mixpanel::getInstance("XXX");
    }

    private function startSession() {
      $this->mp->track('Session');
    }

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `private` only has meaning when used within a class. Here you are trying to define a private method outside the context of a class. Even if this were inside a class.  Your function scope would not have access to a globally defined `$mp` variable.  You would likely need to pass that variable to the method as a parameter.